# Detect WIFI BSSID changes

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Is it possible to detect BSSID changes in the same network with the same SSID ?
so when your mobile switchs to another access point, it fires a broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 1):

yes, it is possible.

Create a BroadcastReceiver and register it to WifiManager action SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.

In your onReceive, get the value of the WifiManager.EXTRA_NEW_STATE via intent.getParcelableExtra(). You can safely cast it to a SupplicantState object.

If the state is COMPLETED, you can get the BSSID from WifiInfo (WifiManager.getConnectionInfo).